# Pointing an exe to a dll outside of the executable's directory

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll

Using C#, VS2012, windows server 2012r2

I did some searching on this and i think I already know the answer, but was hoping someone could let me know if i am correct.

I have a website which has a dll in the bin folder. I've also got several executable tools that run on demand or a scheduled basis and pretty much all of them use the same dll as the wesbite. or rather, they use a copy of that dll which resides in each exe's folder.

This is pretty bothersome since anytime I update that dll for the website, all those exe's are now using an older version of the dll. So I'd like it if i could point all the exe's to the websites bin folder and use the dll in there.

I'd prefer not modifying windows PATH value if at all possible. if so it looks like would need to use a function called LoadLibrary? I hardly do any windows programming at all so i'm not familiar with this at all. IS this the only (or best) way to do this?

I found this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.net-_2800_c_23002900_.aspx

Do i just create the NativeMethods class and then call GetProcAddress for every method/function i need to call?

I was hoping there was a way to basically just tell the exe to look in a specific folder for the dll with the app.config. Is that not possible?

Thanks

Comment: Is your DLL a managed or unmanaged DLL?

Comment: You might try placing the DLL somewhere, then create symbolic links (requires Vista or later) to it in each of the application bin directories. An update should require only replacing the single link target. I think that should work, but I don't have a lot of experience with symbolic links on Windows, and Windows doesn't seem to provide great tools/management support for them either.

Comment: Managed - all done in .net/C#

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your DLL is a managed DLL (built on .net) since you said that you hardly do any Win32 API programming.

One solution is to install your DLL in [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then every time you update the DLL assembly version and deploy to GAC, you have to redirect your applications to use the latest one. [See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: yes - it's all done in .net/C#. I think i'll try doing the symbolic link as Michael Burr suggested in a comment as that seems a little simpler to do and also means i can update the dll with a regular file copy. if that doesn't work then I'll try deploying to the GAC. Thanks